# Django timezone.now() not returning current datetime when script running using supervisor

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am running python script using supervisor. Script has function `timezone.now()`. This always returns `date` when I started supervisor.

I am not able to find out why timezone giving the wrong date.

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you provide more details? like what date you wanted and what you got and what's your timezone?. just to be point verify that you are working on same timezone as configured in your settings file

Comment: @Gahan Its actually in `UTC`. I want current datetime should return. and yes same timezone set in setting file

Comment: can share your snippet/code? because if it is settings can use timezone

Answer (score 0):

change your `TIME_ZONE` in `settings.py`

TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'

and then try `datetime.now()` it will give time in IST

Comment: actually I want it in UTC. I did changes in setting as well. but when I run the script using supervisor and if i check one day after that running scirpt output it always returns yesterdays date: codesnippest :  `from django.utils import timezone`
`print timezone.now().strftime('%d %b %Y')`

Comment: then show your code output you getting and expected output? will help to sort out

Answer (score 0):

Django has timezone naive and aware datetime objects. [See docs for more details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).

In general if you set `USE_TZ=True` in settings and use `timezone` you get timezone-aware object. From what you've described I think using `datetime` module could be more sufficient.